# One-way JK flip-flop using 74xx109

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, reset

I want to design a flip flop circuit that effectively has one input and one output, as well as a reset trigger, along with clock and power, using a 74ACT109 JK flip flop. Basically, the output and input would power on low, and when the input goes high, the output goes high and won't go back to low unless the `PRE` or `CLR` (whichever is appropriate) pin is brought low, acting as a reset trigger. I tried to wrap my head around the JK flip-flop truth table but I couldn't really think of an appropriate circuit, though I feel that it would involve connecting an output to an input through a resistor. How would I go abaout implementing this?

Comment: to clarify, it sounds like you want a synchronous set and an asynchronous reset?

Comment: @Hearth Yes, my apologies for not making that more clear.

Comment: Then why not just tie K low and use J as your synchronous set, and CLR as your asynchronous reset?

Comment: @Hearth Looking at the datasheet, it looks like that would allow it to toggle back and forth, but I want it to only toggle on the first trigger, even if it's triggered multiple times.

Comment: Oh, K is inverted--tie K high then, not low. Same idea, though.